# group by date_format for each day

Tags: mysql, sql

My I'm having problems with a query.
Here is what I have

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as Counted
    FROM referral_code_logs
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp, '%c/%e/%y');
```

I am trying to see the amount of referrals each day has. The part I'm having problems with is the date_format.

**Table layout**

[image: Table layout]

Here are how the time_stamps are entered in the Table: (month/day/year)
month is 1-12    day is 0-31   year is YY

**Time_stamps**

[image: Time_stamps]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add in the date to the select part:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(time_stamp, '%c/%e/%y'), '%c/%e/%y') as DT
       ,COUNT(id) as Counted
    FROM referral_code_logs
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp, '%c/%e/%y');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!! However it only returned one row and the date was null.

Comment: do you get results if you simply `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp, '%c/%e/%y') 
    FROM referral_code_logs` ?

Comment: Yes, but every row returned a null date

Comment: I suspect something is either wrong with the data in the time_stamp column or something is not right with the DATE_FORMAT function. If you just `SELECT time_stamp FROM referral_code_logs` does that come back with nulls too?

Comment: and ... can you confirm that the datatype of the time_stamp column is indeed a datetime datatype?

Comment: It is a text column :S

Edit: I love you for the below response <3

Comment: ah ha, so you just need to convert it to a date with the STR_TO_DATE function. Edit: love you too <3